# ImageMagick: resize images inside directory

Tags: linux, image-processing, imagemagick

I want to resize all images inside a directory where this directory contains n directories, and inside each directory I have n images.

I tried the following command:

```
for i in picture/*.*; do
  convert $i -resize 240x240\! 
done
```

But an error occurred saying "unable to open image picture/*.*".
How to achieve similar operation.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :

```
for f in `find . -name "*.jpg"`
do
    convert $f -resize 400x400\!  $f
done
```